# Conditional in React Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I'm working on a component that takes in two props, `inside` and `position`. If `inside` is set to `true`, then `position` can be `left` or `bottom`. If inside is set to `false`, then `position` can be `left`, `bottom`, `right` or `top`.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
type InsidePosition = "bottom" | "left"
type OutsidePosition = "top" | "right" | InsidePosition

type CoordinatesProps =
  | { inside: true, position: InsidePosition}
  | { inside: false, position: OutsidePosition}


function Coordinates({ position, inside } : CoordinatesProps) {
  const CoordinateComponent = inside ? InsideCoordinate : OutsideCoordinate;

  return _.times(8, (index: number) => {
    return <CoordinateComponent
      key={ `${ position }-${ index }` }
      index={ index }
      position={ position }
    />;
  });
}
```

The child components, `InsideCoordinate` and `OutsideCoordinate`, are defined like this:

```js
type InsideCoordinateProps = {
  position: InsidePosition,
  index: number,
};

function InsideCoordinate({ position, index }: InsideCoordinateProps) {
  ...
}

type OutsideCoordinateProps = {
  position: OutsidePosition,
  index: number,
};

function OutsideCoordinate({ position, index }: OutsideCoordinateProps) {
  ...
}
```

The problem I'm running into is I'm getting a type error inside of `Coordinates` at `position={ position }`.

```
typescript: Type '"bottom" | "left" | "top" | "right"' is not assignable to type '"bottom" | "left"'.
  Type '"top"' is not assignable to type '"bottom" | "left"'. [2322]
```

I could *cast* the `position` value, but shouldn't the compiler be smart enough to know that `position` can only be `InsidePosition` when the component is `InsideCoordinate`? Am I defining the function's type correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem lately. Seems like TypeScript can't infer the type after restructuring so it doesn't work well with React.

I did something like that:

```
function Coordinates({ position, inside } : CoordinatesProps) {
  const props = inside ? { position, inside } : { position, inside };
```

After this everything started to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can infer that unless you pass it immediately in the ternary check itself like so:

```
function Coordinates({ position, inside }: CoordinatesProps) {
    const CoordinateComponent = inside
        ? (idx: number) => <InsideCoordinate position={position} index={idx} />
        : (idx: number) => (
                <OutsideCoordinate position={position} index={idx} />
          );

    return _.times(8, (index: number) => {
        return CoordinateComponent(index);
    });
}
```